# Converting 'char*' to 'char'. Am I passing this array correctly?

Tags: c++, pointers

So my CS professor gave the whole class a simple assignment. "Write a recursive function that will swap the order of a section in an array of chars." I thought to myself, "Easy. I'll finish this up in about 5 minutes and I'll get to work on my Trig homework before I leave."

This is not what happened.
An hour later, the professor and I are both wondering what on Earth is going wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
void swap(char charList, int start, int stop);

int main()
{
    char myList[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};
    int size = 9;
    printCharList(myList, size);
    swap(myList, 3, 5);           //<--- It doesn't seem to like this call
    return 0;
}

void swap(char charList[], int start, int stop)
{
    char temp
    if(start < stop)
    {
        temp = charList[stop];
        charList[start] = charList[stop];
        charList[stop] = temp;
        swap(charList, start+1, stop-1);
    }
    else
        std::cout << "start > stop\n";
}
```

The code is stupidly simple, so you can imagine my confusion when it refused to compile.
It keeps throwing up an error message suggesting that I am trying to convert a pointer to a char, but I'm almost positive that I've done no such thing.
I'm sure the problem is right in front of my face, but I have had no luck in finding it.
Could you help a guy out?

Comment: you're missing a semicolon, is that in the actual code as well?

Comment: What sort of compiler are you using that doesn't warn about mismatched prototype declaration and function definition? All modern compilers do that.

Comment: There's another bug in the program: temp remembers what charList[stop] was, and then you overwrite charList[start] without saving it.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the temp error right after i posted this, but I was kind of distracted by other simple mistakes.
For the record, I tried this program on two different compilers. Both gave different (but similar) messages.

MS Visual C++ Visual 2010 Express/ /error C2664: 'swap' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [10]' to 'char'/ /Code::Blocks 10.05/ /main.cpp|35|error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' / /main.cpp|35|error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void swap(char, int, int)'|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the header, you declare the signature as

```
void swap(char charList, int start, int stop);
```

you probably want to declare it as

```
void swap(char charList[], int start, int stop);
```

Comment: Mikes answer is technically correct, but it is absolutely essential you understand why the code did not compile and what the correction he has suggested does. Clear understanding C++ (and C) arrays and pointers is an enormous part of using these languages

Comment: You've got to be kidding me. THAT was the problem? Wow. Yeah, that was exactly what I was looking for.
I think I understand WHY this happened. swap() was expecting a char, but it got a pointer to an array of chars instead. That's not even remotely the same thing. I think I've got that right.

Comment: Indeed. But it looks purely like a typo. Not a misunderstanding of the difference between an array and an object.

Comment: Well, thanks for the help Mike. And everyone else. I looked at the declaration several times, but it just never clicked.